# SQLite Update query not affecting anything

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to execute this query, but it's not affecting anything

```
UPDATE main SET IS_ALLOWING='True' WHERE IP_ADDRESS='test';
```

Comment: Show the actual code, and the table data that you want to change.

Comment: Do you actually have a record whose IP address is `test` ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your table has record. And check where clause carefully.